# Is it possible for Java third-party program to read data transfer between server and client?

Tags: java, udp, ip

If you think of a server client pair . Server A and client B. So what I would like to do is a thirdparty program C that reads the data transfer between A and B. Like A <-> C <-> B (= A sends data to B and C reads the data. Also if B sends data to A, C reads it.) I do know ip and port that Server is using and I think it's using UDP. Also, I would like to use just Java, not other applications (like wireshark).. :) If any other data is needed, let me know.

Comment: Write your own HTTP server to install on the router who routes the IP packages to the server and intercept packages for the target IP and port.

Comment: Wow! I will definately try it out. Thank you for great suggestion.

Comment: No problem, always glad to help - and next time take your time and come back asking *concrete* coding questions using a smallest running example depicting your problem and you might get seriously helped.